# Excel 2010 VBA - Grab values based on date, add, insert into different workbook (code included)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Never used VBA before an this morning (Java experience in school) and I need some VBA that looks for dates down a column and if it finds the correct date I set then moves one cell to the right, copies that value (a number), moves back to the left (to the original cell where it found the date), and then down again so it can continue down the column, then adds those values based on dates together and inserts that value into a different workbook. Yes I have researched, and will continue to do so, but I am getting aggravated. Hope this makes sense.

My code runs but I get 0 in Sheet 1 (data is correct in Sheet 2).

Also, how can I change the code so it runs without Sheet 2 being selected before running? (run-time error occurs if it is not).

```
Sub Test()
Dim x As Double
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Select
Do Until Selection.Value = ""
    If Selection.Value = "3/1/2012" Then
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        x = x + ActiveCell.Value
        Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Else
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A20").Value = x


End Sub
```

Comment: I can give you a VBA code but Why not an excel formula?

Comment: I didn't want to use a formula because I need to grab different dates at a whim and then manipulate that sum value again afterwards. I wanted a script that was easy to change when I needed to.

Comment: You can still use formula to grab dates at a whim ;) IF you do not want to use formula in Excel cell, you can use formula in VBA so that you don't write lines of code to loop through cells to just find a simple thing